# Loading data from a text file into a DataGridView and saving

Tags: vb.net, string, datagridview, streamreader, streamwriter

1) How can I get a specific string from a text file to call back to `datagrid`

I would like the format to be identical to this:

```
ronald fernando banker's village philippines 8460999
jeniffer corpuz bulacan,pandacan philippines 8460564
```

I only want the strings:

```
phillippines and 8460999
bulacan,pandacan 8460564
```

to be added to a specific point on a `DataGridView`

2) Would I put all of these values onto different rows?

3) Is it possible to append these to a text file?

so the text files already had this

```
John Cruz 
Manila, Philippines
18
june 28, 1990
```

and add this additional data string

```
Mary Rose Hanford
Manila, Philippines
25
march 27, 1999
```

Comment: Is the text stored in a particular format?  Or is the data formatted differently on each line?  If they are the same, what is the format and what are the rules?  If there is no common format, can you change the format of the data in the file?  Are you in control of that?

Comment: yes. they are all .txt file. in my first question they are positioned in horizontal.

Comment: Right, you said it was a text file.  What I'm asking is, how is the text in the file formatted?  Is each record/row on a separate line?  Are the fields within each record delimited with tabs or commas, or are they fixed-width?

Comment: what i want is each string was in each column and in the same row.

Comment: You still have not answered my question.  Short of some artificial intelligence natural language parsing algorithm, it's impossible to load the data from the text file, as you described, unless you know what the format of the data is.  You have not explained what the format is, so it is therefore impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the String.Format method.

See the MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.80).aspx